# Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler: Custom metric aggregation

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm running a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.
I have a Google cloud Custom-Metric in the path:

```
custom.googleapis.com|web|NAME|2xx
```

I want to create an autoscaling rule that will scale my deployment according to the number of calls.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: NAME
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: NAME
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 6
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metricName: "custom.googleapis.com|web|NAME|2xx"
      targetValue: 500
```

This autoscaling rule is working good if `custom.googleapis.com|web|NAME|2xx` is a single value. In my case, I have to create a `SUM` aggregation function to get the actual value.

[image]

See the highlighted (in yellow) part.

How I can update my `metricName` field in order to SUM all the values?

Comment: setting it to sum won't work properly since the change in number of pods won't change that metric. Ideally, you want to have the metric be an average of requests per backend, since that metric will go up or down based on the number of pods you have

Comment: That's true. Changed it and now it working. Thanks.